# JQPLOT and JQRangeSlider not working together

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jqplot

Hello guys I have a issue with JQPLOT and JQRangerSlider . when I try to use both of them in a single page .  one of it does not work.

which ever file I include later works and earlier does not work ..if I include files of JQPLOt after JQRange Slider      only JQPLOT works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use jQuery.noConflict(); since it could be a case where one plugin runs in say version 1.4.x and the other runs in 1.5.x. Example:-

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
then replace the function($){} in your plugin file with function(j){}
```